# Need to Parse XML in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am a bit old school and I need to be able to parse this document in VB6.

```
<ip>
<results>
<result>
<ip>104.145.4.78</ip>
<host>104.145.4.78</host>
<isp>Allstream Corp.</isp>
<city>Vancouver</city>
<countrycode>CA</countrycode>
<countryname>Canada</countryname>
<latitude>49.2551</latitude>
<longitude>-123.0667</longitude>
</result>
</results>
</ip>
```

There is a website that provides the location of and IP address's and i need to put the city name for about 6000 addresses and this is the best way I can think of except that I cannot find a simple way to get the data off of this page.

Here is the actual website I am using:

```
http://api.geoiplookup.net/?query=104.145.4.78
```

Any help here would be greatly appriciated.  I have spent about 6 hours trying to figure this out and I am sure there is a simple solution but I can't figure out what it is.

Cheers,

Comment: Web scraping is a dubious activity at best.  That site's Terms of Use say: "You may not copy content from this website without our prior permission." and "You may not use a script, agent, application or otherwise query this website in an automated fashion without prior written permission."  Time to find another solution based on a public web service.

Comment: Have you looked up the MSXML library?

Answer (score -2):

If you get each result individually, what you need is just only a basic helper function to tokenize your input data, like this one here:

```
' old school tokenizer
Public Function GetToken(ByVal xmlIn As String, ByVal tagName As String) As Variant
    Dim l as long, p1 As Long, p2 As Long
    l = Len(tagName)
    p1 = InStr(1, xmlIn, "<" + tagName + ">")
    p2 = InStr(p1, xmlIn, "</" + tagName + ">")
    GetToken = Mid(xmlIn, p1 + l + 2, p2 - p1 - l - 2)
End Function
```

...which you can use as follows:

```
' assume your data is in xml
Dim result As String, ip As String, city As String
result = GetToken(xml, "result")
ip = GetToken(result, "ip")
city = GetToken(result, "city")
```

Result:

```
Debug.Print ip, city => 104.145.4.78  Vancouver
```

Moreover, you can easily expand the tokenizer above to get multiple results into an array, if you want.

Comment: This should work but how do I save the data as an XML.  The data being returned is not correct.  I think this is the crux of my problem.  I am using the following code to get the data off of the web but it seems to be saving all of the HTML: 

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    strIPaddress = xlsWS1.cells(j + 2, 3).Value
    objIE.Navigate ("http://api.geoiplookup.net/?query=" & strIPaddress)
    objIE.Visible = True
    str = objIE.Document.DocumentElement.innerHTML
    Call GetToken(str, "city")

Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: Also I I was just able to save the the text on the page programmitically it would solve my issue very easily but that is where I stuck.

Comment: @SumeetBains: you can get the xml part without HTML tags by using `Document.body.innerText` - if you have some trouble feel free to ask another question to get more detail.